# TypeScript - Removing readonly modifier

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, is it possible to remove the readonly modifier from a type?

For example:

```
type Writeable<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] };
```

Usage:

```
interface Foo {
    readonly bar: boolean;
}

let baz: Writeable<Foo>;

baz.bar = true;
```

Is it possible to add a modifier to the type to make all the properties writeable?

Comment: Official TypeScript issue about that feature request: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24509

Answer (score 166, accepted):

There's a way:

```
type Writeable<T extends { [x: string]: any }, K extends string> = {
    [P in K]: T[P];
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Writeable%3CT%20extends%20%7B%20%5Bx%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%20%7D%2C%20K%20extends%20string%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20K%5D%3A%20T%5BP%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20bar%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20baz%3A%20Writeable%3CFoo%2C%20keyof%20Foo%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Abaz.bar%20%3D%20true%3B))

But you can go the opposite way and it will make things much easier:

```
interface Foo {
    bar: boolean;
}

type ReadonlyFoo = Readonly<Foo>;

let baz: Foo;
baz.bar = true; // fine

(baz as ReadonlyFoo).bar = true; // error
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ReadonlyFoo%20%3D%20Readonly%3CFoo%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20baz%3A%20Foo%3B%0D%0Abaz.bar%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20fine%0D%0A%0D%0A(baz%20as%20ReadonlyFoo).bar%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20error))

---

## Update

Since typescript 2.8 there's a new way to do it:

```
type Writeable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P] };
```

If you need your type to be writeable recursively, then:

```
type DeepWriteable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepWriteable<T[P]> };
```

These `type` definitions are called [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types)

Comment: Awesome.  I wonder why this isn't a standard type?  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

Comment: `type Writeable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P] };` works great even for classes used as *T* because when using the `class` keyword in TypeScript, you are actually creating TypeScript `interface` containing all the instance methods and properties of the class! 
*(fyi the second thing created with the TypeScript class keyword is a JavaScript variable with a different (anonymous) constructor function type.)*

Comment: N.B.  this particular implementation fails in many edge cases - I've found the `DeepWritable` from `ts-essentials` has worked well though and is basically a more complete version of the one presented in this answer (handles maps, functions, sets, promises etc).

Comment: FYI: `type Writeable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P] };` works flawlessly for readonly tuple types (usually created from const assertions on array literals) even though it looks like it's geared towards objects only.

Comment: The `DeepWriteable` saved my day, thank you very much!

Comment: Is it possible to remove readonly from only one prop?