# Typescript: [Compile Time] Writable (- readable) array/object with "as const" type narrowing

Tags: typescript, constants, readonly, mutable, narrowing

Using [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), one can nicely narrow an object/array literal's type to its elements.

e.g.

```
const arr = [
  [5, "hello"],
  [5, "bye"],
] as const;

type T = typeof arr; // type T = readonly [readonly [5, "hello"], readonly [5, "bye"]]
```

(Without `as const`, `T` would be `type T = (string | number)[][]`, which is very wide and sometimes unwanted.)

Now, the problem is that as a result of that `as const` the array becomes `readonly` as well, while I just it to have a narrowed type.  So, it cannot be passed to the following function.

```
function fiveLover(pairs: [5, string][]): void {
  pairs.forEach((p) => console.log(p[1]));
}

fiveLover(arr); // Error
```

And the Error is:

> Argument of type `'readonly [readonly [5, "hello"], readonly [5, "bye"]]'` is not assignable to parameter of type `'[5, string][]'`.
> The type `'readonly [readonly [5, "hello"], readonly [5, "bye"]]'` is `'readonly'` and cannot be assigned to the mutable type `'[5, string][]'`.(2345)

### Question

How can I narrow the type, without getting the unwanted `readonly` attribute? (Preferably at the object/array creation time.)

Answer (score 1):

Typescript `as` operator looks a bit hacky for me. I'm trying to avoid it as much as possible.
Please, try next example:

```js
const arr = [
  [5, "hello"],
  [5, "bye"],
] as const;

function fiveLover<T extends ReadonlyArray<readonly [5, string]>>(pairs: T): void {
  pairs.forEach((p) => console.log(p[1]));
}

fiveLover(arr); // No Error
```

Btw, I'm always trying to operate on immutable values.  IF you are not mutating your value, there is no sence to remove `readonly` flag

**UPDATE**

It is possible to infer without `const assertion` but you need to provide literal object instead of reference. There is no other way

```js
function fiveLover<
  Fst extends number,
  Scd extends string,
  Tuple extends [Fst, Scd],
  Tuples extends Tuple[]
>(pairs: [...Tuples]): void {
  pairs.forEach((p) => console.log(p[1]));
}

fiveLover([
  [5, "hello"],
  [5, "bye"],
]); // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAhHAbgUwDIKwJwB5hlkAxAZxmUwA8ZMIATC5CMAWwCNN8AaEsgDKUJjXqMWyKvjgQA5gNIAVMAAcANpnENmrANqUYfYaIC6S5Ks2ZWdXVOtb9Z4AD4AFGoCGcfBQAuZH0AOjCnWzMASiD0BDgxAG9BHz8KEJAEfABRbygACw8vKOQAXjdkKCQKBC0QjQR5L30ARmiogG5gAF9gUAwcPF4PfUF9AFYTACJ8zA0GqYsxyeQprgBPTEWBaI7kAHp95AQAayA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Your solution is not wrong, but it wouldn't work for the cases that the function lives in an external library and we cannot modify it.  And it's very common for libraries not to indulge themselves with nested `readonly<readonly<X>>` types for every single function param.  That's why I was looking for a solution that would focus on the object itself.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get rid of the `readonly` property and make the object or array mutable, we need the following utility function:

```
type DeepWritable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepWritable<T[P]> };
```

(Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43001581)

Now we can do one of the two things:

### Solution 1) Make it mutable at the consumption time

That is:

```
fiveLover(arr as DeepWritable<typeof arr>);
```

Which is great, and keeps the object intact.  But then, if we are using the `arr` array in several places for similar mutable usage, we need to do it every single time.

### Solution 2) Make it mutable at the creation time

Which is what I needed in my real project, since I am using that `arr` object in a lot of places, and it being readonly causes trouble.

The solution would be defining a utility function, which is just an identity function in run-time, but `DeepWritable` in compile-time, as following:

```
function writableIdentity<T>(x: T): DeepWritable<T> {
    return x as DeepWritable<T>;
}

const arr2 = writableIdentity([
  [5, "hello"],
  [5, "bye"],
] as const);

fiveLover(arr2); // Works fine!
```

[TS Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAixhgOpQJYwCGARgDbAA8AKgHxwC8cA3nALRTCEAmEAdqYjgBtAApw8vOAGtgiCADM4VALoAudJhz4iZSlVHK6AXwDcAKDMBjPgGd4hKFAbCzcYQFYANHABEAC2BSUggfZU9XD28fYkRgUPDlOEIbOGteO3MzJBQlZ2zgBSTHEzgAelKEZFQqZw5uPgFhOp5%20QSEvXwCgkLC4Zoa2jujY0OULeQBXXksYPD44eTwAN2AAGQgVqAAKMEI8KBt1du87fF4Ac2UhZQBKdSWIPC5mCN39mwA6eWgAUUJLPxbHY3Bh0NI2CDkD7Bc47IQARluN3MRnGyzWG2A2wcTmSGiwuAIJHIFHyhRxNGRFnKcAAfvSGYymcyWayLGZJtNZvMAO7aYnAACSXGAvFmSGoNC2IHUVDu%20K0RN0kpeAEgODAJlBJCAkikMAT%20craCiLOD7I4AEzOPlK8jC0XixBbIQRY6dQLBeJuoYxOJhMyJPHmqkc9HrTZbHGW5FAA)

This way, the object is only manipulated/converted once, and it can be used as an ordinary, type-narrowed, non-readonly variable anywhere!