# Inconvenience when working `as const` arrays - readonly T[] not assignable to T[] - how to remove readonly modifier from array

Tags: arrays, typescript, readonly

I keep running into this problem all the time ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=28&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gRgDQCZsDMAuvBDKJFAFBUXQwAmIAyiALYCmUAFgJZgBzAOq8eAOQCubAEYcEZNAB4AKjA4APKBzAMyYKbIToiAPgAU+mXIgAuGMoCUqEzADeAXxpNWnHv2Gi3JJW8maICA5UQA)):

```js
const arr = [1,2,3] as const

const doSomethingWithNumbers = <T extends number[]>(numbers: T) => {}

doSomethingWithNumbers(arr)
//                     ^
// Argument of type 'readonly [1, 2, 3]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'.
//  The type 'readonly [1, 2, 3]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'number[]'.
```

I know I can modify the function to also take `readonly` arrays:

```js
export type AllowReadonly<T extends any[]> = T | readonly T[number][]

const doSomethingWithNumbers = <T extends <number[]>>(numbers: AllowReadonly<T>) => {}
```

but then I just run into the exact same problem inside `doSomethingWithNumbers`, since `numbers` parameter can now also be `readonly`.

What is a good way to tackle this issue?

Comment: Maybe you'd prefer an alternative to `as const` that doesn't infer `readonly` but does infer tuples and literals, as shown in [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WkGZjW).  If so I could write up an answer explaining it; let me know.

Comment: Thank you for this, @jcalz! I'm trying to make up my mind about which approach is less intimidating for my peers who are new to TypeScript :) Either way, I find this code fascinating. I played around with it to get a grasp on how it works, and I think I get it for the most part, but I don't get this: How does `{ [k: string]: T }` cause the exact tuple values to get preserved (`[1,2,3]` vs `[number, number, number]` when I delete this part), when `[1,2,3]` is not assignable to `{ [k: string]: Narrowable }` ?

Comment: Also, I think it would be nice and interesting if you wrote up the answer as you offered, but I marked the question as a duplicate, so I'm not sure if it makes quite as much sense to you as it did before I did that - depends on your intentions :) Either way, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

##### EDIT:

I found [this even better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43001581/10467064) in a question that aims to remove `readonly` modifier not only from arrays, but also objects.

This is the approach that works for both arrays and objects: [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gRgDQCZsDMAuvBDKJFAFAXQwAmIAyiALYCmUAFgJZgDmAdR7cAcgFdWAI3YIyaADwAVGOwAeUdmHpkwkmQnREAfAAo902RABcMJQEpUxmAG8AvlSrqADiASwoAE9vdhgAQQAbCJAAdwAldjhGMAjA5VUNLR14MECjZzQVAB8YBETk1Lt0CwMiIyogkJhBBBFEqQj2ZQLXGABaMqTwSvQABRg+GABrdkCQADM7IlslMZI3AG5PWlgy1hAAN3YEoZTA1Bh09U1tMkjo+PLhtLhc-LNEBBXHFGdP0marU0cA6XSUxm24DoYHAJwqgTCSAue0OxyeZ1Mn0cMAA9DiMDgYPgYMQqIwWBxuHwhCIuBJLHJzLD0alEQhsTBObj8aIQKokH4YJ4gA)

---

##### Original answer:

One way I found is using this function to remove the `readonly` modifier when passing into the function:

```js
const removeReadonly = <T extends any>(arr: T[] | readonly T[]): T[] => arr as T[]
```

usage ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gRgDQCZsDMAuvBDKJFAFBUXQwAmIAyiALYCmUAFgJZgBzAOq8eAOQCubAEYcEZNAB4AKjA4APKBzAMyYKbIToiAPgAU+mXIgAuGMoCUqEzADeAXxp1YCDmxAAbhwAShxwTGAANgCeqDAqaprauvBg0eaICHbKxjAAPjC+4eAx9sYO2bkoLpmkZURe4PRg4KHFUdEAgkhxvv5BbRExZplOMAD04zBmmPkwuHMEDsZUTKycPPzCotySVvIWrWFDXUhjMBcTU2IgakggyDRAA)):

```js
const arr = [1,2,3] as const

const doSomethingWithNumbers = <T extends number[]>(numbers: T) => {}

const removeReadonly = <T extends any>(arr: T[] | (readonly T[])): T[] => arr as T[];

const nonReadonlyArr = removeReadonly(arr)  // (1 | 2 | 3)[];
doSomethingWithNumbers(nonReadonlyArr)      // No error;
```